# jQuery mobile - cancel pageinit event depending on condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I am using jQuery mobile 1.2 and I am trying to write some code to handle all pages initializations.

For example let's say that I need to check if an user is first logged-in to the application before do some actions in each page. In case the user is not logged-in I should redirected to another page, for example to login.

Example, the code below should be executed before each page initialization:

```
$(document).live('pagebeforecreate', function(event) {
if (ifUserIsNOTLoggedIn()) {
    $.mobile.changePage("login.html");
    event.preventDefault();
}});
```

Page A:

```
$('#a').live('pageinit', function () {
// Do things });
```

Page B:

```
$('#b').live('pageinit', function () {
// Do things });
```

The pagebeforecreate code should run before the pageinit (which by default is triggered correctly) but also should cancel the page transition to A or B and the pageinit should no be triggered.

Could you please help me how can i cancel the pageinit events from the "pagebeforecreate" section?

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents, but page redirection is something that should be done on the server side if possible, e.g: if  you make a request for a page, the server code would verify whether or not you are authenticated. If you are, it would return the page you asked for, otherwise it would return the login page.

If for whatever reason you have to do everything client side, you should check if the user is logged in before ever changing page. If `pagebeforecreate` is fired, then the page *will* be created, it's too late to change your mind about it (probably).

From the [jQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html):

> Note that by binding to pagebeforecreate, you can manipulate markup
>   before jQuery Mobile's default widgets are auto-initialized. For
>   example, say you want to add data attributes via JavaScript instead of
>   in the HTML source, this is the event you'd use.

To me this reads like the event handler for pagebeforecreate is intended only for modifying the page which is about to be shown. It seems that the better event to use to accomplish what you're doing is the `pagebeforechange` event:

> This event is triggered prior to any page loading or transition.
>   Callbacks can prevent execution of the changePage() function by
>   calling preventDefault on the event object passed into the callback. 
>   (...) It should be noted that callbacks can modify both the toPage and
>   options properties to alter the behavior of the current changePage()
>   call. So for example, the toPage can be mapped to a different url from
>   within a callback to do a sort of redirect.

Comment: The reason that i am not using server side redirection is that i am trying to use the aforementioned technique in order to apply common rules for all my pages. The login was just an example that everyone is familiar with. In other words i want to implement some kind of ...aspect in javascript. There is a common logic that i want to shared with all pages which should cancel the page transition in case some rules are triggered